# Rails: Clarifying purpose of precompile:assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to understand what exactly precompiling:assets does, because I've realized that for my last project my CSS would never update when I pushed my app to heroku unless I typed `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`, but this only started happening towards the end, so I believe I probably added something to the config file.

I'm currently trying to understand caching, which made me think about precompile:assets. Is precompile:assets similar to caching by pre-loading the assets to the web server so that those assets aren't loaded directly from the Rails stack? This is for performance purposes right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caching is a related, but separate topic.

The purpose of compiling assets includes the combining and minimizing of assets, e.g. javascript that is all on 1 line with 1 letter variables, as opposed to the originals which are used in development mode and let you debug there using the original source code.

Answer (score 1):

You can find everything you need to know in the [Asset Pipeline Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).